# How to get big sample files(2-3GB) of Revit model

Tags: autodesk, revit

I was working with some sample file which is near about 200MB, now i want to check some real time scenario with big files. guys, please suggest me any resource site so i can get those files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to [The Building Coder public Revit models](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2016/01/happy-new-top-cad-blog-public-models-and-forge.html#4) – the second, updated, link.

If they are still too small for you, I suggest that you implement some automatic model generation code that adds more elements to the BIM.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeremy Tammik!!

Comment: My pleasure entirely. If you yourself create or run into any others, please feel free to share them with us. I can add them there as well.